# I'm trying to add a string to an array in a singleton

Tags: ios, singleton, nsmutablearray

Below is the code in my singleton to add a string to an array. The first NSLog returns the correct string but the second NSLog does not and returns null. If there is any relevant code I need to add let me know. Thanks.

```
 +(void) addArray:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"%@",string);

    Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
    [shared.array addObject:string];

    NSLog(@"array: %@", shared.array);
}
```

I added this code to my singleton.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

In another part of my program I run this code and it prints out the correct information

```
+(void) setPoints:(int) points
{
    Singleton *shared = [Singleton sharedManager];
    shared.points = points;
    NSLog(@"%d",shared.points);
}
```

Here is my Singleton method

```
+ (Singleton *)sharedManager
{
    static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your code for `sharedManager`? Is it along the lines of http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're initializing the `array` again (once in init, again in `sharedManager`). Frankly, I don't even see what `array` initialization in `sharedManager` is referencing (it's a class method, so how are you accessing an property/instance variable?!?). Or is `array` not defined as a property of `Singleton`?

Comment: The fact that you're successfully referencing `array` in class method is confusing to me. The only way you could be doing that is if, in addition to your `array` property, you also have some global var or something like that lingering about...

Comment: Maybe you can share your `@interface` clauses for `Singleton`. (Sorry to drag you through broken glass on this ... but we just don't have enough here to diagnose what's going on.)

Comment: Needless to say, if `array` in your `sharedManager` is successfully referencing something other than a class property, then maybe your class property is never getting set correctly. (By the way, this is why I (a) don't explicitly declare my ivars; and (b) I preface my ivars with an underscore, e.g. `@synthesize array = _array;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you forgot to alloc-init array in your Singleton init.

Comment: I added the code above to alloc and initiate it. And the same thing happens.

Comment: And [Singleton sharedManager] for sure returns a valid Singleton and not nil?

Comment: Ive used it for every other part of my program. Variables like total, tax, final, points..etc and it returns the correct information on all of those things. Those were all more primitive file types but they all worked.

Comment: I posted code that is very similar but a different method that works perfectly.

Comment: I'm guessing you already have, but have you stepped through in the debugger to verify that shared and shared.array are both not nil right before your addObject line?

Comment: Shared.array was null. How do I fix that?

Comment: We might need to see your [Singleton sharedManager] code, but I'm guessing that your init method that you posted just isn't getting called and thus array never gets setup.

Comment: As Robert said, you really shouldn't be able to access array like that in sharedManager. In sharedManager it would only be accessed as a property of sharedInstance, by sharedInstance.array or [sharedInstance array]

Comment: That fixed it. I changed array = [NSMutable...etc to sharedInstance.array = ...etc and that fixed it. Thank you for your help.